# "el" listener not working in Sencha Touch 2

Tags: javascript, dom-events, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I'm using Sencha Touch 2.0-pr3. I'm having trouble getting the element tap event to work (note that BrowsePage extends Ext.Panel). I'm confused cause this works in Sencha Touch 1. What's changed?!

```
var resultsPage = Ext.create('bla.myapp.BrowsePage', {
  id: 'searchResults',
  html: str,               
  listeners: {
    el: {
      tap: function() {
        console.log('hi!');
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone answered my questions here: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?161806-%E2%80%9Cel%E2%80%9D-listener-not-working-in-Sencha-Touch-2&p=691670&viewfull=1#post691670

It's not in ST2 yet, so for now override initialize() --

```
initialize: function() {
    this.callParent();

    this.element.on({
    ...
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi,this realy worked out without MVC.but where do I put in my controller?This doesnt work: `control: {panelContainer:
            {
                tap: 'ChangeProjectOu'
            }}`

Answer (score 0):

Ext.Panel does not fire the 'tap' event.

Have a look at the Sencha Touch 2 API docs to see which events which classes fire:

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Panel

Comment: The API docs are not very complete.. you have to look at the source.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var resultsPage = Ext.create('bla.myapp.BrowsePage', {
  id: 'searchResults',
  html: str,               
  listeners: {
    tap: {
        element: 'element',
        fn: function(e) {
            console.log('hi!');
        }
    }
}
})
```